# Split view on iPad, suggestions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm a starter in dev on iPad and I would like to make a split view.
I have a left menu (like a tab bar but vertical and on the left), a header (already the same for all views) and a container on the centre of the screen with some data...

I'm using the storyboard (also starter with that).

The structure of the app looks like a web page. In storyboard, I used 3 containers:

- 1 for my left menu
- 1 for my header
- 1 for my main container.

The problem is: How can I refresh my main container with the data corresponding to my items menu ?

Example:

- Menu => tapp on Item1 => display data from Item1ViewController in the
  main container
- Menu => tapp on Item2 => display data from Item2ViewController in the
  main container
- Menu => tapp on Item3 => display data from Item3ViewController in the
  main container

...

You know what I mean ? Here is my storyboard structure:

[image]

Thank you all for your suggestions and explanations, I'm really lost actually.

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried but I have some issues I know understand:
First, here is my AppDelegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    self.mainViewController = [[MainContainerViewController alloc] init]; // MainContainer which can be refreshed with some other viewControllers...

    self.dashboardController = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init]; // The first viewController to load in the mainViewController
    
    [self setDetailViewController:self.dashboardController]; // Method to set the viewController I want to load in the mainViewController
    
    [self setup];

    return YES;
}
```

Method to set de viewController:

```
- (void)setDetailViewController:(id)controller
{
    self.mainViewController = controller;
}
```

I set in my storyboard a viewController which is a class of MainViewController (The main container...) and a viewController which is a class of DashboardViewController.
When app is launching, the viewDidLoad method of my DashboardViewController is not called, only the init method, why ?

Here how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

Thank you for help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You create both the side menuViewController and the mainViewController in the app delegate file
2. In your menuViewController file you will have of course your table containing
   all your menu items, and when selected will call a method that will look something like this

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       NSString *methodToCall  = [[[[self.menuTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"RowTitles"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"method"];
       if([methodToCall length] > 0){
           SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(methodToCall);
           [self performSelector:s];
       }
   }
   ```

where I just stored all my menu titles and their method names in an NSMutableDictionary and call their appropriate selectors. Or you could just do a simple if else statement,

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){ 
    [self loadNewScreenOnMainController];
}
```

and in that selector I do something like this:

```
-(void)loadNewScreenOnMainController{
    ProductsVC *productsVC = [[ProductsVC alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *productsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:productsVC];
    [[AppDelegate appDelegate] setDetailViewController:productsNav];
}
```

}

The idea is to call a method in your app delegate that will switch the mainViewcontroller with the view controller from the sidemenu view controller

and then in your `appDelegate.m file you will have a method that looks like this:

```
-(void)setDetailViewController:(id)newController{
    mainViewController = newController;
}
```

Have a look at [Matt gemmett's splitviewcontroller example](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) where he uses this same method to switch a new view controller onto the main viewcontroller from the sidemenuViewcontroller

Comment: @Lapinou I've completed the answer for you which also includes an idea of wat to put in your app delegate that will be responsible for your final main controller switch.

Comment: Hi Pavan! Thank you for your help ;) I tried to use your idea but I get some problems to do it. I have updated my post if you want to see my issue. Thank you very much ;)